# form POST does not work on ASP classic with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, post, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have asp files I'm trying to use as part of an existing ASP.NET MVC4 site.

The files, which function perfectly elsewhere, throw a `80004005` error upon accessing the `Request` object, or `Request.Form`.

When the form is empty it doesn't throw an error. Only when data is sent this happens. Debugging w3wp shows that `Request.Form` turns into an object which the ASP can't identify.

Other objects, such as `Request.Cookies` work fine. Submitting the form with `GET` also works, but we're not interested in that.

Where is it our `Form` disappears to? How can we retrieve it?

**EDIT**

I tested the following:

```
<form action="postTo.asp" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And `Request("submit")` threw an error. So did any attempt to access `Request.Form`.

But *this* (`input` has no `name` to it's name):

```
<form action="postTo.asp" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

So `Request("submit")` was simply empty, as was `Request.Form`. (And it threw an error only if I tried to `cInt` it or something)

Comment: Classic ASP and ASP.net are very different.  You can use .asp and .aspx files on the same IIS server if both are emabled, but I wouldn't think it was possible to use classic asp within a .net mvc project

Comment: @John, Not my default choice, you know ;) I'm not trying to get them to communicate, only to get the ASP classic communicate with themselves.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Also, error 80004005 would suggest that you can't connect to an access database.  Could there be a file permission issue, or do you need to enable 32 bit in your app pool so that you can use the JET OLEDB driver

Comment: @John, No code to post. `Request("foo")` throws the exception. Pool is 32 bit, and connects fine to DB.

Comment: You say that when the form is empty there is no error; what is it that you're posting to it that does cause the error?

Comment: @Polynomial, I added an example to the Q

Comment: don't you have to use <form action="postTo.asp" method="post">?

Comment: @ulluoink, yes, of course. It has one, I'll update the Q as well

Comment: @JNF is that the only form on your page?

Comment: @ulluoink might not be.

Comment: and that form youe mention is on postTo.asp or another page?

Comment: @JNF do you happen to have file upload control anywhere? Maybe in some forgotten control? Check the HTML source of the page, if you see `<input type="file" />` it might explain what you describe since Request.Form can't be used after binary data has been read by the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help solve your problem, but I needed the space to format some code for my suggestion.

To check everything back at the most basic level, make a script (`test.asp` or whatever) in the root of the virtual server and put the following code in it:

```
<p>From form: <%= Request("test") %></p>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="Hello World" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

If the test script works, I'd say the problem must be in your ASP code somewhere and perhaps if you post more of it we can help find out what that is. If the above script doesn't work, I can only imagine that your MVC application contains an IIS module that touches POST data in some way to corrupt it in the eyes of the ASP classic interpreter or something along those lines. As far as I'm aware there is no inherent reason why ASP classic can't understand basic POSTed data on a virtual server running an MVC application.

Comment: Does your MVC app have any modules that modify how IIS handles POST data?

Comment: You mean custom modules?

Comment: Yes, or anything that might be modifying how ASP classic is seeing the POST data?

Comment: If you add `<p>Now: <%= Now() %></p>` to the top of `test.asp` does that work (before doing a POST)?